# advice with installing phantomjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm trying to use phantomjs for the first time although I'm strugglin
to get it installed on Windows 7. Im using the Installation Guide at http://phantomjs.org/build.html

In my DOS command prompt I've navigated to my
`D:\openssl\openssl-1.0.0-beta1` folder and typed the following
command:

```
perl Configure VC-WIN32 no-asm --prefix=C:\openssl
```

but it does not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: "it does not work" is not exactly a helpful description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to "install" (use) it, then just grab the exe (inside the zip) from http://phantomjs.org/download.html

Comment: okay great, that's all I need.  Let me see if I can get it working with a simple example now